# Objective C : Ternary operator with multiple statements

Tags: objective-c, ternary-operator

As the title says i was wondering if there is a way to use ternary operators with multiple statements in Objective C.
I know it can be easily done in some other languages like javascript, php, C etc but i couldn't find a solution for Objective C.

I want to implement something like this:

a > b ? ( statement1, statement2, statement3 ) : ( statement1, statement2 );

Basically i just want to avoid a lot of if-else blocks to maintain better code readability. 
Please also suggest if using ternary operators instead of if-else blocks can harm app performance to a noticeable extent.

Comment: This will only convolute your code

Comment: I'm agree, it is unreadable. In this case it really is better to use `if-else`s. Especially in Objective-C, where you are likely to have something like `[self.customDelegate performIncrediblyComplexMethodWithObject:obj1 andAnotherObject:obj2]` instead of a short `statement`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this; just be aware that the ternary operator can only include expressions, including comma expressions. So your statements can only be expressions, assignments, method calls etc. but no if / return / while and so on. And the ternary operator wants a result, so the last expressions in each group must have the same type; you can just add (void) 0 at the end of each list.

That said, you are most definitely not making your code more readable. Everyone reading it will start swearing at you and doubt your mental sanity. So *don't do it*.

Comment: Yes, multiple statements with ternary operators won't help in readability. I just wanted to know how to implement it and this part did the trick "so the last expressions in each group must have the same type". Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The Conditional operator `?:` is not a replacement for an `if`/`else` block. I'm sure you could tweak the logic to make it work, but that would only obscure the meaning more.

My question is, "what are you saving?"

```
a > b ? ( statement1, statement2, statement3 ) : ( statement1, statement2 );
if (a > b) { statement1; statement2; statement3; } else { statement1; statement2; }
```

The `if`/`else` block is a grand total of 7 characters longer.

An even bigger question is, "Can the logic be composed in a better way?"

- Look to see if the flow can be done differently with fewer `if`s.
- Look for places to create sub-routines.

Comment: You are right. I still wanted to know how to do it in objective C. Thanks for suggestions though :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution for your question (@user3752049) is:

`a > b ? ^{ statement1; statement2; statement3;}() : ^{statement1; statement2;}();`

Thanks